Measure theory, prove the countable additivity of measure
I am reading Cohn's Measure Theory, here is an exercise from Chapter 1, Section 2.
Let ($X,\mathcal A,\mu$) be a measure space, and define $\mu^{\star}:\mathcal A\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ by
\begin{equation}
\mu^{\star}(A)＝sup\{\mu(B):B\subset A,B\in\mathcal A 
, and \,\,\mu(B)\leq+\infty\}
\end{equation}
(a) Show that $\mu^{\star}$ is a measure on ($X,\mathcal A$)
(b) Show that if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, then $\mu^{\star}＝\mu$
In terms of the countable additivity of $\mu^{\star}$, here is my approach.
Let $\{A_{k}\}$ be a sequence of disjoint of sets that belong to $\mathcal A$, let $B$ $\subset \bigcup_{k＝1}^{\infty} A_{k}$, thus, $B＝\bigcup_{k＝1}^{\infty}(B\cap A_{k})$, it follows that $\mu (B)＝\sum_{k＝1}^{\infty}\mu(B\cap A_{k})\leq \mu^{\star}(A_{k})$
My question is:

How to prove the reverse inequality holds？
And how to prove (b)?


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem

In the definition of $\mu^*$, do you want to take the supremum on all measurable subsets or on all measurable subsets with finite measure? That is: are you sure you didn't mean $\mu(B)<\infty$?

@Pelota Sorry, I make a mistake , it is $\mu(B)<\infty$, do you have any idea about proving the reverse inequality？or part  (b) of the question？Please share with me，thank you

@geetha290krm   I haven't learned about the concept of  Carathéodory's extension theoremyet, could you give me a hint just using the definition?Thank you very much
